# The code returns an error when the image path has a space on it. How to correct it through the code?

Tags: php

The following code returns an eroor when the $image/$imgsrc has a space on it's path. For example www.domain.com/my pic.gif

However if you add a %20 in it, works correctly. How can I modify it so when the image has a space to run correct without editing the path?

Thank you!

```
<?php function resizeImg($imgsrc ,$maxW='*', $maxH='*', $allowScaleUp=0, $returnHTML="alt='image'"){
 if($s=getimagesize($imgsrc)){
  $oW=$s[0];$oH=$s[1];
  if(($oW>$maxW && $maxW!='*') || ($oH>$maxH && $maxH!='*') || $allowScaleUp){//if resize is needed:
   if($maxW && $maxH=='*'){ //constrain by width:
    $proportion=$oH/$oW;
    $w=$maxW;
    $h=$maxW*$proportion;   
   }else if($maxH && $maxW=='*'){ //constrain by height:
    $proportion=$oW/$oH;
    $h=$maxH;
    $w=$maxH*$proportion;
   }else if(!$maxW && $maxH){ //constrain by smallest side:
    return($oW>$oH ? resizeImg($imgsrc, '*', $maxH, $allowScaleUp, $returnHTML) : resizeImg($imgsrc, $maxW, '*', $allowScaleUp, $returnHTML));
   }else if($maxW && !$maxH){ //constrain by largest side:
    return($oW>$oH ? resizeImg($imgsrc, $maxW, '*', $allowScaleUp, $returnHTML) : resizeImg($imgsrc, '*', $maxH, $allowScaleUp, $returnHTML));
   }else{
    return($maxW>$maxH ? resizeImg($imgsrc, '*', $maxH, $allowScaleUp, $returnHTML) : resizeImg($imgsrc, $maxW, '*', $allowScaleUp, $returnHTML));
   }
  }else{
   $w=$oW;$h=$oH;
  }
  //echo "orig: ".$oW."x:".$oH."<br />max: ".$maxW."x".$maxH."<br />new: ".$w."x".$h."<br />"; //debug
  $w=round($w); $h=round($h);
  return ($returnHTML ? "<img src='$imgsrc' width='$w' height='$h' $returnHTML />" : array(0=>$w,1=>$h,"width"=>$w,"height"=>$h));
 }else{//file does not exist or is not an image:
  return false;
 }
}
?>


<?php echo resizeImg($picture,250,'*') ?>
```

Comment: Can you give a longer example, you do not have enough code for us to understand what your entire site is doing.

Comment: It "returns" what error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, getimagesize requires a proper, valid URI if you use the URI binding. So, replace spaces with `%20` ([see example #3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)).

`urlencode` encodes all sorts of entities, so my recommendation is: `if ($s = getimagesize(str_replace(' ', '%20', $imgsrc))) {`

Comment: @alex: My current one can be taken as a synonym. :)